# SQL: Sum and groupby, criteria for groupby in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, one which contains raw data for individual departments and earnings with multiple lines per department. I need a sum of each field by it's parent department, data which is mapped in another table. I have a longer version of the following statement that works for summarizing by individual department:
`SELECT a.Dept, Sum(a.Earnings) as Earnings
FROM Source AS a 
GROUP BY a.Dept;`
What I have been struggling with is I need to summarize each department not by its department but by its parent department, and this mapping information is stored in a separate table. I have tried different joins and am not exactly getting the results I am looking for. Here is a (incorrect) query I wrote which gives me a listing of parent departments but excludes departments that don't have a parent department and also gives the wrong totals:
`SELECT
r.ParentDept, 
sum(a.Earnings) AS Earnings, 
FROM EarningsTable a inner JOIN ParentTable r ON a.Dept = r.Dept group by r.ParentDept;`
and  Below is what I am trying to achieve, thanks in advance.

Table1:
`Dept   Earnings
4          1000
4          16767
8          2456
9          2456
10         3456
3          36543`

Table2(mapping table):
`Dept   ParentDept
4           1
8           1
9           2
10          2
3           3`
Table3(Results Table):
`ParentDept     Earnings
1                20233
2                5912
3                36543`

Comment: If there is no parent associated with department how would you group the departments?

Comment: If there is no parent then I need the data summarized the same way it was in my initial query, just by its own department

Comment: hope the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is query but is for SQL Server which i had tested your scenerio:

```
select ISNULL(p.parentdept,c.dept),SUM(c.earning) from child c left join parent 
p on p.dept=c.dept group by ISNULL(p.parentdept,c.dept)
```

For MS-Access NZ() is to replace null values (NZ() is equivalent to ISNULL()).

Untested but should work:

```
select NZ(p.parentdept,c.dept),SUM(c.earning) from child c left join parent 
p on p.dept=c.dept group by NZ(p.parentdept,c.dept)
```

if the query doesn't work ...Hope at least you got an idea to solve the problem. :)

Comment: I used the second example and it worked flawlessly, thank you so much for your help! I also want to thank you for making me look into the NZ function a bit more! Good to know

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query may be it's work.

SELECT a.ID (select(select Sum(ear.Earnings)as totalEarning from Earning as ear where dep.DepID= ear.EarningID) Dept as dep)
    FROM ParentDept AS a 
    GROUP BY a.ID;